# Where and orderby calause in sql eloquent model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I need one more ->Where and ->orderBy and ->limit in my below eloquent query.

value for these fiels  should come from below php variable code

i want to add these (where,orderby,limit) in sql query some thing like below

```
->where =  $where
->orderBy = $order_by
->limit = $offset,$page_size.
```

```js
$offset=4;
 $page_size=5

 if (isset($query_array['training_center_name'])) {
            $trainingCenter = $query_array['training_center_name'];
            $where .= " AND user_organizations.organization_name = '$trainingCenter'";
        }

 $order_by = " ORDER BY user_template.update_date DESC";
        if (isset($query_array['order-by'])) {
            $field_order = explode(',', $query_array['order-by']);
            if ($field_order[0] == 'area') {
                $order_by = " ORDER BY user_template.area $field_order[1]";
            } elseif ($field_order[0] == "center_name") {
                $order_by = " ORDER BY user_organizations.organization_name $field_order[1]";
            } else {
                $order_by = " ORDER BY user_template.$field_order[0] $field_order[1]";
            }
        }
       
        $query = UserTemplateModel:: Select('user_template.org_id'')
        ->join('user_organizations', 'user_template.org_id', 'user_organizations.org_id')
        ->join('user_organization_users', 'user_organizations.org_id', 'user_organization_users.org_id')
        ->where('user_organization_users.user_id',$userId)
        ->where('user_template.status',ACTIVE)
        ->get();
        $query_result = $query->toArray();
        return $query_result;
```

Comment: I really cannot follow you, what do you need and where and why?

Comment: @Zollie i just want sql query in eloquent way,and need to add one more  where,orderby condition into it,or in short need to append this $where,$orderby in my sql query.

Comment: ohh, OK, I'm getting you now.